# How to mock axios call within a method?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to mock an axios call within a vuejs method. Is this possible?

Here is my vue component (SomeObj):

```
 methods:{
        callAxiosMethod() { 
          const callApi= axios.create();
          callApi.defaults.timeout = 10000;
          callApi.get(mockedUrl)
          .then(response => {
             console.log('response is ' + response);
          })
          .catch(e => {});
        }
    }
```

Here is my spec.js

```
let mockData = {};
beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mockData));
    });

    let wrapper = shallowMount(SomeObj, {
        stubs: [], localVue, mocks: {
            mockUrl: mockUrl,
            $route: {
                params: { testId: "123" }
            }
        }
    });
    it('is a Vue instance', () => {
        expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue(mockData);
        wrapper.vm.callAxiosMethod();
    })
```

When I looked at the coverage, the system says the callApi is not covered. Any idea on how I can mock the axios call within the function?

Answer (score 1):

Your code calls [`axios.create`](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance) so you need to mock that function to return a mock `callApi` object.

Here is a simplified working example:

code.js

```js
import * as axios from 'axios';

const mockedUrl = 'http://mock-url';

export const callAxiosMethod = () => {
  const callApi = axios.create();
  callApi.defaults.timeout = 10000;
  return callApi.get(mockedUrl);  // <= return the Promise so it can be awaited
}
```

code.test.js

```js
import { callAxiosMethod } from './code';

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    defaults: {},
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('mocked data')
  })
}));

test('callAxiosMethod', async () => {  // <= async test function
  const response = await callAxiosMethod();  // <= await the Promise
  expect(response).toBe('mocked data');  // Success!
});
```

Comment: thanks Brian for the info. I used it and there was no error. However, in my coverage, it says that the callApi.get(mockedUrl) was not covered. Would you know why?

Comment: I updated my answer to use `jest.mock` with a [factory function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) since it's a little cleaner.

Comment: hmm...not sure why it wouldn't consider `callApi.get(mockedUrl)` covered.  Did you return the `Promise` and `await` it?  Is the `catch` still in your code...if it is you'll need to add a test that throws an error to get that covered.  @arn-arn